# Unlocking SSD without password?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, lock

Is it possible to unlock a locked(not encrypted as far as i know) SSD without knowing the password?

I already tried to unlock it with `hdparm` on linux with the default master password for the disk which I found online (32 times 't'). Also tried various tools like `blancco` to erase it without success. The SSD is a `Samsung pm871` which is torn out of a laptop.

I really do not care for the data, just want the SSD to function somewhat normally. Anyone got an idea what I could try or at least tell me that it is not possible?

Here's what `hdparm -I /dev/sda` returns

```
/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       SAMSUNG MZ7LN128HCHP-000L1              
    Serial Number:      S1ZMNXAH235673      
    Firmware Revision:  EMT04L0Q
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0039) 
    Supported: 9 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 9
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:   16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:  250069680
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:  250069680
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:      122104 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:      128035 MBytes (128 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: Solid State Device
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
       *    Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    NOP cmd
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
            Write-Read-Verify feature set
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Phy event counters
       *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
       *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
            Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Asynchronous notification (eg. media change)
       *    Software settings preservation
            Device Sleep (DEVSLP)
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
       *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
       *    DOWNLOAD MICROCODE DMA command
       *    SET MAX SETPASSWORD/UNLOCK DMA commands
       *    WRITE BUFFER DMA command
       *    READ BUFFER DMA command
       *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 16385
        supported
        enabled
        locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    Security level maximum
    2min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 8min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5002538d00000000
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 002538
    Unique ID   : d00000000
Device Sleep:
    DEVSLP Exit Timeout (DETO): 50 ms (drive)
    Minimum DEVSLP Assertion Time (MDAT): 30 ms (drive)
Checksum: correct
```

Comment: If you can tell us how the drive gets locked, we can provide you with further help.

Comment: It asks for a password when booting up. Looks something like [this](http://biospro.com/images/ppid_hard_drive_password.JPG) (not actual picture but very similar). And when i dismiss it or enter a wrong code it just says someting like _hard disk locked_